# sh: ts-node-dev: command not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I used this package on a project, only to try run it today and get the error (on the same machine)

`sh: ts-node-dev: command not found`

I have removed the `package-lock.json` and reinstalled the package but still shows the same error.

This is my script tag from 4 months ago (when it works).

```
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev index.ts",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

What is the potential solution and cause of such and possible cause?

Comment: do you have ts-node-dev [installed in devDependencies](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev#install)?

Comment: try first install `ts-node-dev` dependency with `npm install ts-node-dev` if npm is your package manager